# Image transfering btween JavaFX and Android via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying implement a simple file transfering app.

My app does like that: 
1. Capture current camera preview in Android
2. Send it to Javafx application via Bluetooth
3. When Javafx app received the image saving it and show on the window
4. After some drawing over the image capture it then send it to Android again

I implemented like this on Android side first

I created a kind of packet which contains file size, actual data and eof.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    // filesize + data + end of file
    String fileSize = String.valueOf(baos.size());
    fileSize += '\0'; // end of the filesize string
    String eof = "eof"; // end of packet
    // set packet size
    int packetSize = fileSize.length() + baos.size() + eof.length();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packetSize);
    byteBuffer.put(fileSize.getBytes());
    byteBuffer.put(baos.toByteArray());
    byteBuffer.put(eof.getBytes());

    byte[] data = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
    byteBuffer.position(0);
    byteBuffer.get(data);
```

and send the data to bluetooth outputstream socket

On JavaFX side,

```
bytes = btIn.read(buffer);
                // receive packet data
                if (fileSize == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                        if (buffer[i] == '\0') {
                            fileSize = new String(buffer, 0, i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // eof offset
                int offset = bytes - 3;
                byte[] eofByte = new byte[3];
                eofByte = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, offset, bytes);
                String message = new String(eofByte, 0, 3);

                if (message.equals("eof")) {
                    eof = true;
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytes-3);
                } else {
                    // set buffer size to file size
                    if (fileBuffer == null) {
                        fileBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.parseInt(fileSize));
                        fileBuffer.put(buffer, fileSize.length()+1, bytes);
                        fos.write(buffer, fileSize.length()+1, bytes);
                    } else {
                        fileBuffer.put(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        // for progress bar
                        percent = (float) fileBuffer.position() / (float) fileBuffer.capacity();
                    }
                }

                log(String.valueOf(percent));

                if (eof) {
                    byte[] data = new byte[fileBuffer.capacity()];
                    fileBuffer.position(0);
                    fileBuffer.get(data);
                    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(input);
                    image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);

                    if (bufferedImage != null) {
                        log("got the image");
                    }

                    // set null fileBuffer and fileSize for next images
                    fileSize = null;
                    fileBuffer = null;
                }
            }
```

above code is for receving image from the Anroid

and Sending part on JavaFX is:

```
            WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight());
            canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            log(String.valueOf(imageInBytes.length));
            bct.write(imageInBytes);
            String eof = "end of file";
            byte[] eofbyte = eof.getBytes();
            bct.write(eofbyte);
```

the sending and receiving part work fine..
But I have problems on result images

[image]

This is JavaFX side when received the image from Android and ss you see, the most left side of the image is not desired

and more weired after receving image from JavaFX side the result image on Android like this:

[image]

My question is how should I fix the code to get correct images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were hit by this bug:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041459

You can avoid this problem by using PNG instead of JPG. Another option is to explicitly convert the image into an image without alpha component before storing it.

Michael

Comment: That was right. I fixed it by re-saving image without alpha channel. Thanks for the answering